# DDD - Building Repositories

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, aggregate

If I have a Repository designed for obtaining my Aggregate Root (as defined by Eric Evans DDD) e.g. an Order Entity (the Root Aggregate) which would have OrderLine objects as children.

In some cases I just want to retrieve the top level object i.e. the Order without the OrderLines and on other occasions I would like to bring back a bit more, maybe down 2 levels etc. i.e. the Order and the associated OrderLines.

The Order / OrderLine scenario is a simple example but what if my Aggregate Root was deeper than this, possibly going down 3 or 4 levels.

What is the best / accepted way of building this into the Repository (using eager loading)??

Comment: Eager loading is an implementation issue, are you using an ORM like Hibernate?

Comment: @Kdeveloper I am using EF4 as my ORM

Comment: I don't know about EF4, but in JPA/Hibernate you can declare relations on Classes as lazy loading, but in a query you can force them by 'FETCH JOIN' to become eagerly loaded for the query. This way, you can make them eagerly loading whenever you need them to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Udi Dahan talked about Intentional Interfaces at TechEd 2008. In his presentation he talked about how to fetch entities from repository intentionally. You can watch his [presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Making-Roles-Explicit-Udi-Dahan) or [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/deimos/udi-dahan-intentions-and-interfaces).

The idea behind is that you fetch entities based on what to you want to accomplish. For example if you want to complete order then you create interface `ICompleteOrder` with `Complete` method and map specific `FetchingStrategy` to it. Then you can use something like `Repository.Find<ICompleteOrder>(orderIdentity)` and get this entity as you specified in `FetchingStrategy`.

Comment: I think this sounds like the way I should be going, can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks

Comment: One way is to create IFetchingStrategy<T> with Apply(ICriteria) method and in Repository methods you can resolve fetching strategy from IoC container and apply it. You may write default fetching strategy as well, then you don't have to check if you get something back from IoC container. You can read more from Udi Dahan's post (http://www.udidahan.com/2007/09/16/fetching-strategy-nhibernate-implementation-available/)

Answer (score 1):

A single model **cannot** be appropriate for reporting, searching, and transactional (business unit of work) behaviors. Your domain model should mainly focus on transactional behavior of a business unit of work (and also some queries...say (hypothetical e.g) Customer.allAccounts()).

I suggest you look at extended thought process on DDD called CQRS here http://gojko.net/2010/06/11/evolution-of-ddd-cqrs-and-event-sourcing/

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what do you mean by Aggregate Root. As far as I know the Repository Pattern usually works with a cluster of objects that are part of your domain model, in DDD this usually refers as [aggregates](https://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx). How do you access you objects from a repository depends on what kind of data access layer you use in you application. I usually use NHibernate as and ORM that manages all the relationships between my classes and database tables, so when I implement a repository I can use any objects that are a part of my domain and access them as needed.

Here is an example of a repository that uses different objects:

```
public interface IStoryRepository : IRepository<Story>
{
   List<Image> GetStoryImage(int id);
   List<FacebookUser> GetFbUserById(string id);
}

public class StoryRepository : Repository<Story>, IStoryRepository
{
   public List<Image> GetStoryImage(int id)
   {
       var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Image))
       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id))
       .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
        return criteria.List<Image>() as List<Image>;
    }

    public List<FacebookUser> GetFbUserById(string id)
    {
       var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(FacebookUser))
       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id))
       .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());

        return criteria.List<FacebookUser>() as List<FacebookUser>;
     }
}
```

Comment: That cluster of objects is what is referred to as the aggregate, the aggregate root is the top-level object that you would ask the repository to provide, it has global identity.

Comment: In my case If I needed to use eager loading I would use: .SetFetchMode("Story", FetchMode.Eager)